# Updating beliefs about a continuous variable via evidence represented with empirical distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, inference, conditional-probability

I have a system with a latent variable T and two pieces of evidence - E₁ and E₂. Each piece of evidence is represented with an empirical distribution (space of all possible values of T has been subdivided into N bins, number of observations falling into each bin has been counted, and for each bin we know the proportion of all events that would fall into that bin). What I'm trying to do is to find a way to combine the evidence to produce a better guess about the true value of variable T, assuming an uninformative prior.

In technical terms, I'm looking for a function that would take two 1-dimensional array e1 and e2 of length N, where each element represents the proportion of events falling within the bucket i, and returns a single 1-dimensional array g1 of length N, which represents a new guess about the true value of T.

In case it would be helpful, here is a visualization from the simulation of the system:
[image: probability density plots of E1, E2 and desired conditional probability]

Comment: Do you have the counts as well as the proportions that fell into each bin?

Comment: @jbowman, I can definitely pull this information for the simulation example, would you like me to update this question with the plot with the exact counts? For me the problem is that this information won't be available to me in production, so if solution relies on it, I'd have to find a way to estimate it.